# Heroku not running collectstatic with Django

Tags: django, heroku

So I have a Django app, I've turned off `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC` but there's no mention of collect static happening.

Some research showed that Heroku would fail silently if collect static fails, but would write out during the build log when collect static succeeds. I did `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic` and it ran correctly. No errors.

However, collect static still isn't running on build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The catch turned out to be that to disable a config var, one must use:
 `heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC`

I was using the wrong command since `heroku config` displayed initally `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC: 1` I assumed `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=0` would turn off the config var. Since nothing else seemed off, this assumption became the next likely suspect. Following Heroku docs about handling config, I ran all of 
 `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=false`
`heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=False` which don't work as desired.